# R 'right click' open csv file with R/Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, right-click, shortcut-file

Is it possible to 'Right Click' on a CSV file an choose R/Rstudio.

Currently the options I have when I right click are 'Open with Sublime Text', 'Open with Excel', 'Open with Notepad'.

It'd be cool if I can have such option directly instead of launching RStudio, then copy paste the csv file into a folder, and only then load it into R environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. If you are doing a right-mouse-click on a file, choose  and then  the apps will be listed and you can take RStudio to open the file.
The file (txt, csv) will be opened but not imported inside RStudio.

A comfortable more visual way to import files into R is the per default available Import Dataset function inside RStudio:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR0aZ.jpg)
That provides you different import formats.

Comment: I tried on a file, but it says 'selected file too large'. Reason is file is bigger than 5MB. My expectation is, by opening in RStudio, it automatically reads the file as a tibble or dataframe.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible because of a simple reason: RStudio is not able to decide which object should be used automatically. Open a file with the editor is possible - I already tested that with a file >5MB.

Comment: Yeah, if somehow we can define a default which method should be used to open a csv file, it’d be great. Of course there can be some edge cases for for typical files, it should be ok